# How do I move /home to a raidz pool/dataset?

Tags: mount, home-directory, zfs

This question has been raised but never answered in a way that I was able to get to work.

Goal:  Install Ubuntu disk 1 and move /home to a 3 disk raidz.

Progress:  Installed Ubuntu with the 'experimental' zfs file system on a 1TB drive. Three 2TB drives used for zpool configured as raidz and named zhome.  zfs dataset created named home.

zpool status

pool: bpool
state: ONLINE
scan: none requested
config:

```
NAME                               STATE     READ WRIT  CKSUM
bpool                               ONLINE     0     0     0
```

303e0a42-8a9d-6a41-87de-9eba201128bd    ONLINE     0     0     0

errors: No known data errors

pool: rpool
state: ONLINE
scan: none requested
config:

NAME                                  STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
rpool                                 ONLINE       0     0     0
d282d21c-f3ab-c24b-bff6-846a1327654a  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors

pool: zhome
state: ONLINE
scan: none requested
config:

```
NAME                        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
zhome                       ONLINE       0     0     0
  raidz1-0                  ONLINE       0     0     0
    wwn-0x5002538f3191984e  ONLINE       0     0     0
    wwn-0x500a0751e4fa5033  ONLINE       0     0     0
    wwn-0x500a0751e4fa5440  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

errors: No known data errors

File system successfully copied from /home to zhome/home using

cp -a /home/* /zhome/home

As noted in the below link, ZFS by default rejects mount points that contain something which can be changed by setting overlay to on.

zfs set overlay=on zhome

The next step is the changing the mountpoint to /home by

zfs set mountpoint=/home zhome/home

zfs list

**NAME         USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT**

zhome        174M  3.52T      128K  /zhome

zhome/home   173M  3.52T      173M  /home

df -h -t zfs

**Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on**

zhome/home      3.6T  2.7G  3.6T   1% /home

zhome           3.6T  128K  3.6T   1% /zhome

All of the above accepted by my system, but on reboot, programs like stacer don't list my larger raidz, but that the system is still writing to the original /home on the 1TB drive.

I looked at this reference ([Migrating /home to ZFS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081238/migrating-home-to-zfs)) which the asker was never able to get the response to work.  Me neither.  Some answers say add XXX to /etc/fstab while others say not necessary.   I think I am close.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? ZFS is not experimental anymore ...

Comment: It was on my install disk.  Running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: @matigo ZFS installation on root [is still experimental on Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/blog/tag/zfs).

Comment: @ScottAlbright welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please [take the tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) to learn how Ask Ubuntu works. Read [how to ask](https://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of your question.

Comment: I don't really want to install the OS on the zfs, Just applicable file storage (music, documents et al).  The series of steps  for zfs on root is way over my ability to troubleshoot.  https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/Ubuntu/Ubuntu%2020.04%20Root%20on%20ZFS.html